# adding homepage in Reactjs makes Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs app when I run it in development mode with `npm start` everything works well
but when I run it with serve -s build in production mode I get  `Unexpected token '<'` in the browser console, I recognized that when I remove homepage from package.json everything works well again but I need the homepage to run my app from another path than root one I tried `"homepage": "nemouneh/"` and also `"homepage": "https:mysite/nemouneh/"`

full error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.5b79d421.js:1:1)`

the main.5b79d421.js file :

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/nemouneh/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/nemouneh/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/nemouneh/manifest.json"/><title>React App</title><script defer="defer" src="/nemouneh/static/js/main.5b79d421.js"></script><link href="/nemouneh/static/css/main.e1e5a846.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Could you share some code that you have, it could be that the issue is coming from the HTML, or the ReactJS code, but we would need to see code and/or the full error message to help more. Also, the value for `homepage`  looks incorrect as a URL string.

Comment: @Harrison i made an edit i home this helps

Comment: Close the page and restart the server, the warning for the line number is likely not pointing you to the correct place. As I said, the `homepage` URL could be an issue, it may need to be `"homepage": "/nemouneh"` instead?

Comment: i tried that too but still same error

Comment: Having the name `main.5b79d421.js` implies it's either a hot-update, or the code is running from a built version (`npm build`) which means any changes wouldn't propagate to it